# ParserError: Expected pragma, import directive or contract/interface/library definition

Tags: solidity, remix

I'm getting this error when trying to compile my code:

`ParserError: Expected pragma, import directive or contract/interface/library definition.`

The error is on line 96.

```
pragma solidity >=0.4.22 <0.6.0;

contract owned {
    address public owner;

    constructor() public {
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    modifier onlyOwner {
        require(msg.sender == owner);
        _;
    }

    function transferOwnership(address newOwner) onlyOwner public {
        owner = newOwner;
    }
}

interface tokenRecipient { function receiveApproval(address _from, uint256 _value, address _token, bytes calldata _extraData) external; }

contract AntiCoin is owned {

    uint256 public sellPrice;
    uint256 public buyPrice;

    mapping (address => bool) public frozenAccount;

    /* This generates a public event on the blockchain that will notify clients */
    event FrozenFunds(address target, bool frozen);

    /* Initializes contract with initial supply tokens to the creator of the contract */
    constructor(
        uint256 initialSupply,
        string memory tokenName,
        string memory tokenSymbol
    ) AntiCoin(initialSupply, tokenName, tokenSymbol) public {}

    /* Internal transfer, only can be called by this contract */
    function _transfer(address _from, address _to, uint _value) internal {
        require (_to != address(0x0));                          // Prevent transfer to 0x0 address. Use burn() instead
        require (balanceOf[_from] >= _value);                   // Check if the sender has enough
        require (balanceOf[_to] + _value >= balanceOf[_to]);    // Check for overflows
        require(!frozenAccount[_from]);                         // Check if sender is frozen
        require(!frozenAccount[_to]);                           // Check if recipient is frozen
        balanceOf[_from] -= _value;                             // Subtract from the sender
        balanceOf[_to] += _value;                               // Add the same to the recipient
        emit Transfer(_from, _to, _value);
    }

    /// @notice Create `mintedAmount` tokens and send it to `target`
    /// @param target Address to receive the tokens
    /// @param mintedAmount the amount of tokens it will receive
    function mintToken(address target, uint256 mintedAmount) onlyOwner public {
        balanceOf[target] += mintedAmount;
        totalSupply += mintedAmount;
        emit Transfer(address(0), address(this), mintedAmount);
        emit Transfer(address(this), target, mintedAmount);
    }

    /// @notice `freeze? Prevent | Allow` `target` from sending & receiving tokens
    /// @param target Address to be frozen
    /// @param freeze either to freeze it or not
    function freezeAccount(address target, bool freeze) onlyOwner public {
        frozenAccount[target] = freeze;
        emit FrozenFunds(target, freeze);
    }

    /// @notice Allow users to buy tokens for `newBuyPrice` eth and sell tokens for `newSellPrice` eth
    /// @param newSellPrice Price the users can sell to the contract
    /// @param newBuyPrice Price users can buy from the contract
    function setPrices(uint256 newSellPrice, uint256 newBuyPrice) onlyOwner public {
        sellPrice = newSellPrice;
        buyPrice = newBuyPrice;
    }

    /// @notice Buy tokens from contract by sending ether
    function buy() payable public {
        uint amount = msg.value / buyPrice;                 // calculates the amount
        _transfer(address(this), msg.sender, amount);       // makes the transfers
    }

    /// @notice Sell `amount` tokens to contract
    /// @param amount amount of tokens to be sold
    function sell(uint256 amount) public {
        address myAddress = address(this);
        require(myAddress.balance >= amount * sellPrice);   // checks if the contract has enough ether to buy
        _transfer(msg.sender, address(this), amount);       // makes the transfers
        msg.sender.transfer(amount * sellPrice);            // sends ether to the seller. It's important to do this last to avoid recursion attacks
    }
}

    /**
     * Internal transfer, only can be called by this contract
     */
    function _transfer (address _from, address _to, uint _value) internal {
        // Prevent transfer to 0x0 address. Use burn() instead
        require(_to != address(0x0));
        // Check if the sender has enough
        require(balanceOf[_from] >= _value);
        // Check for overflows
        require(balanceOf[_to] + _value > balanceOf[_to]);
        // Save this for an assertion in the future
        uint previousBalances = balanceOf[_from] + balanceOf[_to];
        // Subtract from the sender
        balanceOf[_from] -= _value;
        // Add the same to the recipient
        balanceOf[_to] += _value;
        emit Transfer(_from, _to, _value);
        // Asserts are used to use static analysis to find bugs in your code. They should never fail
        assert(balanceOf[_from] + balanceOf[_to] == previousBalances);
    }

    /**
     * Transfer tokens
     *
     * Send `_value` tokens to `_to` from your account
     *
     * @param _to The address of the recipient
     * @param _value the amount to send
     */
    function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success) {
        _transfer(msg.sender, _to, _value);
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Transfer tokens from other address
     *
     * Send `_value` tokens to `_to` in behalf of `_from`
     *
     * @param _from The address of the sender
     * @param _to The address of the recipient
     * @param _value the amount to send
     */
    function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success) {
        require(_value <= allowance[_from][msg.sender]);     // Check allowance
        allowance[_from][msg.sender] -= _value;
        _transfer(_from, _to, _value);
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Set allowance for other address
     *
     * Allows `_spender` to spend no more than `_value` tokens in your behalf
     *
     * @param _spender The address authorized to spend
     * @param _value the max amount they can spend
     */
    function approve(address _spender, uint256 _value) public
        returns (bool success) {
        allowance[msg.sender][_spender] = _value;
        emit Approval(msg.sender, _spender, _value);
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Set allowance for other address and notify
     *
     * Allows `_spender` to spend no more than `_value` tokens in your behalf, and then ping the contract about it
     *
     * @param _spender The address authorized to spend
     * @param _value the max amount they can spend
     * @param _extraData some extra information to send to the approved contract
     */
    function approveAndCall(address _spender, uint256 _value, bytes memory _extraData)
        public
        returns (bool success) {
        tokenRecipient spender = tokenRecipient(_spender);
        if (approve(_spender, _value)) {
            spender.receiveApproval(msg.sender, _value, address(this), _extraData);
            return true;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Destroy tokens
     *
     * Remove `_value` tokens from the system irreversibly
     *
     * @param _value the amount of money to burn
     */
    function burn(uint256 _value) public returns (bool success) {
        require(balanceOf[msg.sender] >= _value);   // Check if the sender has enough
        balanceOf[msg.sender] -= _value;            // Subtract from the sender
        totalSupply -= _value;                      // Updates totalSupply
        emit Burn(msg.sender, _value);
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Destroy tokens from other account
     *
     * Remove `_value` tokens from the system irreversibly on behalf of `_from`.
     *
     * @param _from the address of the sender
     * @param _value the amount of money to burn
     */
    function burnFrom(address _from, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success) {
        require(balanceOf[_from] >= _value);                // Check if the targeted balance is enough
        require(_value <= allowance[_from][msg.sender]);    // Check allowance
        balanceOf[_from] -= _value;                         // Subtract from the targeted balance
        allowance[_from][msg.sender] -= _value;             // Subtract from the sender's allowance
        totalSupply -= _value;                              // Update totalSupply
        emit Burn(_from, _value);
        return true;
    }
}
```

**EDIT: I've made suggested edits and I no longer get errors but when trying to deploy to the Rinkeby Test Network, it does not function normally (every transaction fails).**

If someone could look over this code, deploy it, and make changes, that would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

***UPDATED CODE:***

```
pragma solidity >=0.4.22 <0.6.0;

contract owned {
    address public owner;

    constructor() public {
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    modifier onlyOwner {
        require(msg.sender == owner);
        _;
    }

    function transferOwnership(address newOwner) onlyOwner public {
        owner = newOwner;
    }
}

interface tokenRecipient { function receiveApproval(address _from, uint256 _value, address _token, bytes calldata _extraData) external; }

contract AntiCoin is owned {

    uint256 public sellPrice;
    uint256 public buyPrice;

    mapping (address => bool) public frozenAccount;

    /* This generates a public event on the blockchain that will notify clients */
    event FrozenFunds(address target, bool frozen);

    /* Initializes contract with initial supply tokens to the creator of the contract */
    constructor(
        uint256 initialSupply,
        string memory tokenName,
        string memory tokenSymbol
    ) AntiCoin(initialSupply, tokenName, tokenSymbol) public {}

    mapping(address => uint256) public balanceOf;
    event Transfer(address from, address to, uint256 value);
    uint256 public totalSupply;
    mapping(address => mapping(address => uint256)) public allowance;
    event Approval(address owner, address spender, uint256 value);
    event Burn(address who, uint256 value);

    /* Internal transfer, only can be called by this contract */
    function _transfer(address _from, address _to, uint _value) internal {
        require (_to != address(0x0));                          // Prevent transfer to 0x0 address. Use burn() instead
        require (balanceOf[_from] >= _value);                   // Check if the sender has enough
        require (balanceOf[_to] + _value >= balanceOf[_to]);    // Check for overflows
        require(!frozenAccount[_from]);                         // Check if sender is frozen
        require(!frozenAccount[_to]);                           // Check if recipient is frozen
        balanceOf[_from] -= _value;                             // Subtract from the sender
        balanceOf[_to] += _value;                               // Add the same to the recipient
        emit Transfer(_from, _to, _value);
    }

    /// @notice Create `mintedAmount` tokens and send it to `target`
    /// @param target Address to receive the tokens
    /// @param mintedAmount the amount of tokens it will receive
    function mintToken(address target, uint256 mintedAmount) onlyOwner public {
        balanceOf[target] += mintedAmount;
        totalSupply += mintedAmount;
        emit Transfer(address(0), address(this), mintedAmount);
        emit Transfer(address(this), target, mintedAmount);
    }

    /// @notice `freeze? Prevent | Allow` `target` from sending & receiving tokens
    /// @param target Address to be frozen
    /// @param freeze either to freeze it or not
    function freezeAccount(address target, bool freeze) onlyOwner public {
        frozenAccount[target] = freeze;
        emit FrozenFunds(target, freeze);
    }

    /// @notice Allow users to buy tokens for `newBuyPrice` eth and sell tokens for `newSellPrice` eth
    /// @param newSellPrice Price the users can sell to the contract
    /// @param newBuyPrice Price users can buy from the contract
    function setPrices(uint256 newSellPrice, uint256 newBuyPrice) onlyOwner public {
        sellPrice = newSellPrice;
        buyPrice = newBuyPrice;
    }

    /// @notice Buy tokens from contract by sending ether
    function buy() payable public {
        uint amount = msg.value / buyPrice;                 // calculates the amount
        _transfer(address(this), msg.sender, amount);       // makes the transfers
    }

    /// @notice Sell `amount` tokens to contract
    /// @param amount amount of tokens to be sold
    function sell(uint256 amount) public {
        address myAddress = address(this);
        require(myAddress.balance >= amount * sellPrice);   // checks if the contract has enough ether to buy
        _transfer(msg.sender, address(this), amount);       // makes the transfers
        msg.sender.transfer(amount * sellPrice);            // sends ether to the seller. It's important to do this last to avoid recursion attacks
    }


    /**
     * Internal transfer, only can be called by this contract
     */

    /**
     * Transfer tokens
     *
     * Send `_value` tokens to `_to` from your account
     *
     * @param _to The address of the recipient
     * @param _value the amount to send
     */
    function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success) {
        _transfer(msg.sender, _to, _value);
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Transfer tokens from other address
     *
     * Send `_value` tokens to `_to` in behalf of `_from`
     *
     * @param _from The address of the sender
     * @param _to The address of the recipient
     * @param _value the amount to send
     */
    function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success) {
        require(_value <= allowance[_from][msg.sender]);     // Check allowance
        allowance[_from][msg.sender] -= _value;
        _transfer(_from, _to, _value);
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Set allowance for other address
     *
     * Allows `_spender` to spend no more than `_value` tokens in your behalf
     *
     * @param _spender The address authorized to spend
     * @param _value the max amount they can spend
     */
    function approve(address _spender, uint256 _value) public
        returns (bool success) {
        allowance[msg.sender][_spender] = _value;
        emit Approval(msg.sender, _spender, _value);
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Set allowance for other address and notify
     *
     * Allows `_spender` to spend no more than `_value` tokens in your behalf, and then ping the contract about it
     *
     * @param _spender The address authorized to spend
     * @param _value the max amount they can spend
     * @param _extraData some extra information to send to the approved contract
     */
    function approveAndCall(address _spender, uint256 _value, bytes memory _extraData)
        public
        returns (bool success) {
        tokenRecipient spender = tokenRecipient(_spender);
        if (approve(_spender, _value)) {
            spender.receiveApproval(msg.sender, _value, address(this), _extraData);
            return true;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Destroy tokens
     *
     * Remove `_value` tokens from the system irreversibly
     *
     * @param _value the amount of money to burn
     */
    function burn(uint256 _value) public returns (bool success) {
        require(balanceOf[msg.sender] >= _value);   // Check if the sender has enough
        balanceOf[msg.sender] -= _value;            // Subtract from the sender
        totalSupply -= _value;                      // Updates totalSupply
        emit Burn(msg.sender, _value);
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Destroy tokens from other account
     *
     * Remove `_value` tokens from the system irreversibly on behalf of `_from`.
     *
     * @param _from the address of the sender
     * @param _value the amount of money to burn
     */
    function burnFrom(address _from, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success) {
        require(balanceOf[_from] >= _value);                // Check if the targeted balance is enough
        require(_value <= allowance[_from][msg.sender]);    // Check allowance
        balanceOf[_from] -= _value;                         // Subtract from the targeted balance
        allowance[_from][msg.sender] -= _value;             // Subtract from the sender's allowance
        totalSupply -= _value;                              // Update totalSupply
        emit Burn(_from, _value);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Check you curly braces. This became a 15 minute bug that only required deleting one curly brace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't declare a function outside of a contract. My guess is that the right curly brace on line 91 (closing the contract) was unintentional.

**EDIT**

Deleting the curly brace on line 91 fixes the problem, but there are a number  of other compilation issues in the code. I was able to get it all to compile by adding some missing declarations:

```
mapping(address => uint256) public balanceOf;
event Transfer(address from, address to, uint256 value);
uint256 public totalSupply;
mapping(address => mapping(address => uint256)) public allowance;
event Approval(address owner, address spender, uint256 value);
event Burn(address who, uint256 value);
```

and deleting one of the duplicate `_transfer()` functions. (At a glance, they appeared identical except for formatting.)

Comment: Regardless of whether I put the functions inside or outside of the contract, I get the same error, it just moves the error to a different line.

Comment: I'm not sure what edit you made. Did you delete the curly brace on line 91? If that wasn't the edit, please share your updated code. (Preferably, edit it into your question here rather than linking elsewhere.)

Comment: See my edit for what it took for me to get a successful compilation.

Comment: I made your advised changes, please see the updated code and comments.

Comment: Please post a new question for this. The original issue you had is resolved, and future developers don't benefit from two questions being crammed into one post. (It makes it hard to search and find what you need help with.)